# Context for getting access token that needs to be passed to Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, access-token, microsoft-graph-api, openid-connect

On my initial analysis on the fetching the access token from Azure AD using OpenID connect protocol, I came to know that there are two ways to consider

1. Fetching access token using the signed in user's context where caching is used.
2. Fetching access token using application context.

Can anyone help me to know which needs to be consider with some example code.

Answer (score 0):

To fetch an access token to the graph API, you need to:

- redirect the user to the Azure authorization endpoint (`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`),
- to get back an authorization token,
- that you need to provide Azure with, on the access token endpoint (`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token`), with your application credentials.
- Finally, you can provide this access token to the userinfo endpoint on the graph API: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`

> with some example code

I've written a sample code, but it depends totally on the language, environment and OIDC library you are using. In case you are using Java in a servlet environment with the MIT implementation of OIDC (MITREid Connect), my example to access the Microsoft graph API by means of OIDC on Azure is available on GitHub here: https://github.com/AlexandreFenyo/mitreid-azure

Answer (score 0):

> > Fetching access token using the signed in user's context where caching is used.

OpenID Connect implements authentication as an extension to the OAuth 2.0 authorization process. It provides information about the end user in the form of an id_token that verifies the identity of the user and provides basic profile information about the user.

Please refer to code sample :[Calling a web API in a web app using Azure AD and OpenID Connect](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect) ,this sample uses the OpenID Connect ASP.Net OWIN middleware and ADAL .Net. In controller , you could get access token for specific resource using the signed in user's context :

```
string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Startup.Authority, new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectID));
ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
result = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(todoListResourceId, credential, new UserIdentifier(userObjectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));
```

> > Fetching access token using application context.

What do you mean by "application context" ? If you are talking about OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials Grant Flow , which permits a web service (confidential client) to use its own credentials instead of impersonating a user, to authenticate when calling another web service. You could refer to this [scenario explanation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#daemon-or-server-application-to-web-api) and [code samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-code-samples#server-or-daemon-application-to-web-api) .